# python: log unusual crashes in a text file

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, exception, crash

I want to write to a file, the time of crash with a message, when my script crashes for any reason. But I am unable to do that. My script is supposed to run in background and never stops unless I do it on purpose. Now it is crashing and I am working on the crash but I just want to know whenever it crashes and write the time in file. I am working with python 2.7 on Linux

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    print ('Starting body_detection')
    body_det = multiprocessing.Process(target=body_detection )
    body_det.start()

    print('Starting start_upload')

    upload_body_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=start_upload)
    upload_body_process.start()
    upload_body_process.join()
```

Above main I have all my functions and variables defined.

Comment: use try except to catch your error and output the time

Comment: @Eumel I am using try catch everywhere in my code but Its not working for every exit. I want to write time when my script crashes. I will work on why it is crashing part later.

Comment: use it over the whole main function then

Answer (score 0):

Please read [Python logging howto](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html). Here is some code from that page. It will automatically write time of each message.

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
logging.info('So should this')
logging.warning('And this, too')
```

You also can catch your exception and write it to log. Use [traceback](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html) to get exception message.

If you can't catch exception, then just launch python inside a bash script, which will print time when python exits. Your `.sh`:

```
python test.py                                                                   
echo `date`
```